# What exactly does Time.stub(:now) {fake_time} do?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm going through an rspec tutorial and I just need help confirming what the following code means:

```
@eleven_am = Time.parse("2011-1-2 11:00:00")
Time.stub(:now) { @eleven_am }
```

I think it means I'm going to pretend the time right now is January 2, 2011 even though it isn't.  Is that what's going on?

Comment: Yes, that's what's going on. If you're going through the tutorial and not running the specs IMO you're skipping out on the important part. Running the spec would almost certainly confirm the answer to this question.

Comment: Pro Tip: In "real" specs, use https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop to avoid headaches with stubbing Time.

Comment: Minitest also has a reference to the `stub` method, see documentation for an example
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub

Answer (score 4):

Yep, a stub redefines a method to do whatever you decide for your test. Usually they are used to avoid non-deterministic methods (like `Time.now`, which obviously returns a different value every time and is thus very hard to test), or to gloss over methods that do not relate to the current test.

There's a few ways to write stubs. The example you've shown uses the block form, which allows you to dynamically decide the return value for the method and so can be used for quite complicated things (essentially you can entirely redefine the method, although this is not usually a good idea!).

You can write "static" stubs (that just return a value, and unlike the block form cannot compute it fresh each time). There are a couple of syntaxes for that:

```
# Hash form, useful for stubbing multiple things at once
Time.stub(:now => @eleven_am, :then => @ten_am)

# and_return, which reads fluently
Time.stub(:now).and_return(@eleven_am)
```

In the example you've shown you don't *need* the block form because the value to be returned is the same every time. Then, it's just a matter of personal taste which one you prefer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what the stub method does is intercept whatever message you are sending, and instead of calling that method on the object, it just returns the value you tell it to, in this case the value of @eleven_am.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else strolls along and notices this, I'll add a warning.  `Time.stub(:now)` only stubs out the Time class.  If your code relies anything (including other libraries) that might call the Date class, you need to make sure that's stubbed out as well, otherwise you now have two different clocks in your test.